# A connection between the Gelfand Naimark Theorem and the GNS construction

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian $C^*$ algebra. By the Gelfand Naimark theorem, we know $\mathcal{A}$ is isometrically $*$ isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}_0(\Delta_{\mathcal{A}})$ where $\Delta_{\mathcal{A}}$ is the space of non zero characters on $\mathcal{A}$. We have that $\Delta_{\mathcal{A}}$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space.

Now by the GNS construction, we know every $C^*$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$ admits a faithful representation into some $\mathcal{B(H)}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space i.e. $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subalgebra of a  $\mathcal{B(H)}$.

My question is whether for abelian $C^*$ algebras, can we say something more specific regarding the embedding $\mathcal{B(H)}$ using the Gelfand Naimark Theorem?

Note: I was thinking along the lines of getting the irreducible representations of $\mathcal{A}$ which are in direct correspondence with the **pure states** of $\mathcal{A}$ which are exactly the characters on $\mathcal{A}$ as it is abelian.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters of $C_0(X)$ are the maps $\{ ev_x\mid x\in X\}$ where $ev_x: C_0(X)\to\Bbb C$ is given by $f\mapsto f(x)$. As such the associated semi-definite inner-product $(,)_{ev_x}$ is given by:
$$(f,g)_{ev_x}:= ev_x(f^* g) =\overline{f(x)}\cdot g(x)$$
And clearly $C_0(X) /N_{ev_x}\cong\Bbb C$ where $N_{ev_x}$ is the null space of $(,)_{ev_x}$. The isomorphism $C_0(X)/N_{ev_x}\to \Bbb C$ is given by $[g]\mapsto g(x)$ as you can check explicitly. Now the action of $C_0(X)$ on this Hilbert space is given by:

$$f\cdot [g] = [f\cdot g]$$
which, under the above isomorphism $C_0(X)/N_{ev_x}\cong \Bbb C$, corresponds to:
$$f\cdot z = f(x)\cdot z$$

Now if you put all this together what you get is that the GNS space is:
$$H= \bigoplus_{x\in X} \Bbb C = \ell^2(X)$$
and the representation is defined by:
$$(\pi(f) v)_{x} = (f(x)\cdot v_x)$$
For some $v = (v_x)_{x\in X}\in \ell^2(X)$.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this after a long time. You have taken the direct sum only over the characters of $C_0(X)$ which are just the pure states. For the universal representation, you need to take the direct sum over all the states. Now I agree that taking only the pure states gives you a faithful representation, but is there any way to characterize all the states of $C_0(X)$?

Comment: Yes, the states of $C_0(X)$ are the probability Radon measures on $X$. If you carry out the analogous argument as above you get that
$$H=\bigoplus_{\mu \in P_1(X)} L^2(\mu)$$
(note that the pure states / characters correspond to the Dirac measures, and $L^2(\delta_x) \cong \Bbb C$, as a comptability statement with the above)